# Find pairs with least difference

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an array of numbers `3,1,3,5` and a number k with the value `3`. I want to find pairs whose absolute adjacent difference between them is the smallest. Find k such pairs.

All possible pairs are :

```
|3 - 1| = 2
|3 - 3| = 0
|3 - 5| = 2
|1 - 3| = 2
|1 - 5| = 4
|3 - 5| = 2

For smallest k = 3 values are [0,2,2] is the required answer
```

My approach:

```
public static List<Integer> process(List<Integer> list, int k) {
    int n = list.size();
    List<Integer> all = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.sort(list);
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        for(int j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
            all.add(list.get(j) - list.get(i));
        }
    }
    Collections.sort(all);
    List<Integer> answer = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0; i<k; i++) {
        answer.add(all.get(i));
    }
    
    return answer;
}
```

Here I am trying to get all possible pairs and then get the smallest values. so time complexity is more for this program. How to reduce time complexity for this task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Python solution.  It is somewhat similar to what was already suggested, except that putting values back into the heap allows non-adjacent differences to also be discovered.

Translation to Java left as an exercise for the reader.

```
import heapq
def closest_differences (elements, limit=None):
    e = sorted(elements)
    best = []
    for i in range(len(elements)-1):
        best.append((e[i+1] - e[i], i, i+1))

    heapq.heapify(best)
    yielded = 0
    while 0 < len(best):
        value, i, j = heapq.heappop(best)
        yield value
        yielded += 1
        if limit is not None and limit <= yielded:
            break
        if j+1 < len(e):
            heapq.heappush(best, (e[j+1] - e[i], i, j+1))


for d in closest_differences([3, 1, 3, 5], 3):
    print(d)
```

Comment: In java I don't have yeild or yielded, can you please share another code without these keywords

Comment: @learner `yield value` in this answer translates to `all.add(value);` in your code. There's nothing special about `yielded`, it's just a variable.

Comment: @user3386109 That, and you stop when you have enough values.

Comment: what is the complexity of this?

Comment: @SomeDude It is `O(n log(n))` for the sort, `O(n)` for the `heapify`, and `O(k log(n))` to produce the `k` best pairs.  For a total complexity of `O((n + k)log(n))`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a max heap/priority queue of size `k`.
2. Use a nested loop to iterate over all possible differences.
3. For each difference between consecutive elements, push the difference to the heap if `heap.max > difference`

`O(n^2)` for iteration, `O(n^2 logk)` for heap.
Total time complexity: `O(n^2 logk)`
Total space complexity: `O(k)` (for heap)

In your approach, you've sorted the list of all `n^2` differences, so that has a complexity of `O(n^2 logn)`.

Comment: `Iterate over the array. For each difference between consecutive elements, push the difference to the heap if heap.max > difference` can you please share pseudo code for this

Comment: `since the closest difference will then be guaranteed to be between adjacent elements` - that is true for minimum difference only, but we need to find `k` smallest differences, that means we should consider non-adjacent elements too. in that case heap solution will have O(N^2 logN) time complexity as well as OP's: sorting array of N^2 elements

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov corrected the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's an outline of another approach, which avoids the use of a priority queue.

Reformulating the question, we'd like to find the smallest `k` differences in an array `A`, and write it to an output array `R`. Let `count_pairs(arr, d)` be a placeholder function that tells us how many pairs in an array `arr` have a difference less than/equal to `d`. Let `N` be the length of `A`.

1. Sort `A`. Let `B` be the sorted array.
2. Compute difference `d > 0` where `count_pairs(B, d) < k` and `count_pairs(B, d + 1) >= k`. Note `count_pairs(B, 0) >= k` indicates you could just let `R` be an array of `k` zeroes. `d` can be found via binary search from 0 to the difference of the largest and smallest elements in `A`.
3. After finding `d`, pick out the pairs whose difference is less than/equal to `d`. Write their differences to `R`.
4. Fill up the remaining slots in `R` with `d + 1`; there should be exactly `k - count_pairs(B, d)` remaining slots.

Observations

- `count_pairs()` can be implemented in `O(N * log(N))` time via binary search if the input array is sorted. Don't think this can be improved by much.
- If you implement `3.` using binary search (similar to what's done for `count_pairs()`) the time complexity *should* be `O(N * log(N) + count_pairs(B, d))`.
- If `R` needs to be in sorted order, you'll have to sort `R` before returning it, since `3.` won't guarantee this - only that all values are smaller than/equal to `d`.

So, the overall time complexity of each step is as follows:

1. Sorting - `O(N * log(N))`
2. Searching for `d` - `O(log(max(A) - min(A)) * N * log(N))`
3. Fill in the smallest values - `O(N * log(N) + count_pairs(B, d))`
4. Fill in the remaining values of `d + 1` - `O(k - count_pairs(B, d))`

I suspect that `2.` will likely be the bottleneck and would be curious to see how well this approach compares to the priority queue one on actual data.